# for loop with unsigned char gives unexpected behavior

Tags: c++

Im practicing interview questions but am having a hard time with this basic question:

> How many times will this loop execute?

```
  unsigned char half_limit = 150;

  for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 2 * half_limit; ++i)
  {
      std::cout << i;
  }
```

My thought is that since an unsigned int only reaches 255 it will execute forever since when I increment an unsigned char when it is at 255 it will revert back to 0? However this thinking is wrong and what is even more strange is that this is the output cout is giving me:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

And when I try to limit the look with something like the following:

```
if (i <= 255)
  std::cout << i;
else
  break;
```

The loop is still infinite.

My questions is what is the expected result of the code and why is this the case?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this should result in an infinite loop.

Comment: But note that "what makes this a good interview question?" is off-topic here.

Comment: "if (i <= 255)" is *obviously* always true since `i` is `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C/C++ extends expression's bit capacity if necessary. It's called [Integer type promotion](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules).

According to these rules, `half_limit * 2` is getting promoted to integer value of 300. Assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`, `i` is a single octet, and therefore it will never reach value of 300, so the cycle will continue forever. Also, an unsigned octet is always less or equal than 255, so it's your `if` expression is redundant.

Comment: How does this address the question?

Answer (score 8):

This is an infinite loop. Let's take a step-by-step look:

`2 * half_limit`

`half_limit` is `unsigned char` but `2` is `int`. So `half_limit` is promoted to `int` and the result is integer `300`.

`i < 2 * half_limit`

Since right hand size is `int`, `i` is also promoted to `int`. There is no problem here.

But in `++i` no promotion is involved and `i` is an `unsigned char` as declared. So after reaching `255` it goes back to `0` and the condition `i < 2 * half_limit` is always true as `i` will never reach to `300`.

The situation is same for your second condition `if (i <= 255)` as `i` goes back to `0` before this check is made.

Comment: "and `i` is an `unsigned int` as declared" it's actually `unsigned char`. Small typo ;>

Comment: Good answer - and thank you for correcting the typo :)